# Multiple insert after post call in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, http-post

I need to update insert into MYSQL DB same data from a post call.
This is the form code:

```
<form action="salva_debiti.php" method="post">


'; // Create connection $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } $sql = "SELECT * FROM rimanenti_mese WHERE Mese = $mese AND Anno = $anno ORDER BY cognome ASC"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { echo '
<table id="ricambi" style="width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="titolotd">Nome</td>
        <td id="titolotd">Cognome</td>
        <td id="titolotd">Da incassare pezzi</td>
        <td id="titolotd">Da incassare benzina</td>
        <td id="titolotd">Residuo '.$mese_scritto.' '.$anno_pr_div.'</td>
    </tr>'; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo '

    <tr>

        <td>
            <input type="" name="nome[]" value="'.$nome.'">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="" name="cognome[]" value="'.$cognome.'">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="" name="pezzi[]" value="'.$pezzi.'">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="" name="benzina[]" value="'.$benzina.'">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="" name="rimanenti[]" value="'.$rimanenti.'" </td>
    </tr>
    ' ; } echo '
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">'; echo '</form>';
```

And this is the code that I use to insert data:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn - > connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
}

 foreach($_POST['nome'] as $nome) {

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$rimanenti_ins = $_POST['rimanenti'];


//$sql = "UPDATE rimanenti_mese SET Rimanenti='$rimanenti_ins' WHERE Nome='$nome' AND Cognome = '$cognome'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO rimanenti_mese (Nome, Cognome, Mese, Anno, Benzina, Pezzi, Rimanenti)
VALUES('$nome', '$cognome', '09', '2015', 'xxxx', 'fdfdfd', '$rimanenti_ins')
";

}

 if ($conn - > query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: ".$sql.
"<br>".$conn - > error;
}

 $conn - > close();
```

The problem is that it insert only the last row...
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Nice injection hole you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `$conn - > query($sql)` into your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($_POST['nome'] as $nome) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    $rimanenti_ins = $_POST['rimanenti'];
    $sql = ".....";
    if ($conn - > query($sql) === TRUE) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Because now you do only one query, and after your `foreach` loop is over `$sql` contains query for the last item.

**Update**:
word `Array` is a string representation of array value.
When you do `$nome = $_POST['nome']`, your `$_POST['nome']` is array, so adding array to a string results in word `Array`.
So you should take every item of your array per iteration, for example:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $nome) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'][$i];
    $cognome = $_POST['cognome'][$i];
    $rimanenti_ins = $_POST['rimanenti'][$i];

    // sql
    // run query

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error: New record created successfullyError: INSERT INTO rimanenti_mese (Nome, Cognome, Mese, Anno, Benzina, Pezzi, Rimanenti) VALUES ('Array', 'Array', '09', '2015', 'xxxx', 'fdfdfd', 'Array')
Error: INSERT INTO rimanenti_mese (Nome, Cognome, Mese, Anno, Benzina, Pezzi, Rimanenti) VALUES ('Array', 'Array', '09', '2015', 'xxxx', 'fdfdfd', 'Array')
Error: INSERT INTO rimanenti_mese (Nome, Cognome, Mese, Anno, Benzina, Pezzi, Rimanenti) VALUES ('Array', 'Array', '09', '2015', 'xxxx', 'fdfdfd', 'Array')   and it crate a record with the value "Array"

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `$conn -> query($sql)` after the foreach is finished, this means in `$sql` is only stored the last values from the foreach loop.

Try this:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if ( $conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn -> connect_error);
}

foreach ( $_POST['nome'] as $nome ) {

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
    $rimanenti_ins = $_POST['rimanenti'];


//$sql = "UPDATE rimanenti_mese SET Rimanenti='$rimanenti_ins' WHERE Nome='$nome' AND Cognome = '$cognome'";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO rimanenti_mese (Nome, Cognome, Mese, Anno, Benzina, Pezzi, Rimanenti)
VALUES('$nome', '$cognome', '09', '2015', 'xxxx', 'fdfdfd', '$rimanenti_ins')
";

    //put your ->query into the foreach loop
    if ($conn -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: ".$sql.
        "<br>".$conn -> error;
    }
}

$conn -> close();
```

Comment: And bind your parameters.